# Get method arguments via ES7 decorators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-next

I am experimenting with ES7 decorators and writing a method decorator that simply logs the arguments that a method is called with.

It [works in some cases](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojzl87k96y) like `this.sum(6, 5)`, but it does not work with
arrow functions `this.arrowSum(5, 10)` and default arguments `this.sum()`

Am I missing something or it just a limitation in the current decorator implementation?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function logArgs() {
  return function(target, property, descriptor) {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args) {
      console.log(...args);
      return originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  @logArgs()
  sum(a = 1, b = 2) {
    return a * b;
  }

  @logArgs()
  arrowSum = (a = 3, b = 4) => {
    return a * b;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.sum()} <br /> {this.sum(6, 5)}
        <br />
        {this.arrowSum()} <br /> {this.arrowSum(5, 10)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It doesn't work with your `arrowSum` because that's an instance property created in the constructor, not a method, and decorators work differently for those. [class fields are still a proposal only](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Comment: It doesn't work with default arguments because your decorator only logs the *actual* arguments. The default values are inaccessible from outside, they are only created within the function.

Comment: Thanks, my plan was to create memoization via decorators, but I guess it will not be possible for now.